# How to import file in python?

Tags: python, import, cpu-word

How do I import files in python? Right now I'm writing a word game program that needs access to a text file which contains lots of words. How do I import this file (call it words.txt) to my main program script so that I can perform tasks like searching for a particular word from the word list? Do I need to save both files in the same folder? I've tried using different commands like inFile, but the error message always pops out and I don't really know what's the problem.

thanks

update:
thanks for all the answer. I wrote: file = open("hello.txt", 'r'), but it shows 'IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'hello.txt' '. What have I done wrong? I have already saved both files in the same folder in my documents.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: read file line by line into array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/python-read-file-line-by-line-into-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built in function "open" sound like exactly what you need. The "Reading and Writing Files" section at this site: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files is worth the read-through. Essentially you use the open function like so: `readFile = open("filename",'r')` and that save that file to the variable "readFile". Then you can just do a for loop for every line in readFile. If you want to write to the file, you just change the r to a w, and if you want to both read and write from the file, pass in rw. To write, assuming you've opened the file as a write or readwrite, you just call the "write" function like so: `readFile.write("Things I want to say")`and that'll save the text to readFile.

Comment: thanks. I wrote: file = open("hello.txt", 'r'), but it shows 'IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'hello.txt' '. What have I done wrong? I have already saved both files in the same folder in my documents.

Comment: I think "hello.txt" would have to be in the same directory as the python file, but it's a good idea to include the whole path like "/Users/you/Desktop/hello.txt"

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
words = []

with open('words.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
           words.append(word)

for word in words:
    print word
```

---

sorry, you wanted to load words.txt from a subfolder:

```
import os

script_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
relative_path = "textfiles/words.txt"
absolute_path = os.path.join(script_path, relative_path)

words = []

with open(absolute_path,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
           words.append(word)

for word in words:
    print word
```